# Texture not appearing while in object mode

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, 3d-view

I am trying to apply a texture to to my model, but it isn't working and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I UV Mapped the model and colored my texture to fit to the model. When I am in *Texture Paint* mode the model looks fine, but when I switch to *Object Mode* the model becomes white, and I can't figure out why...

Here is Texture Paint Mode:

[image: Texture Paint]

Here is Object Mode:

[image: Object Mode]

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Textures aren't displayed in *Solid view* by default. You can either switch to a higher level shading view which displays textures, such as *textured view* (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>). Or you can enable *Textured solid* in *3D view > Properties region (<kbd>N</kbd>) > Shading*:

[image]

Note that this doesn't affect the final render, only the viewport.

See [the wiki](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View_Options/) for more information.

Comment: I want to export it to fbx then import it into unity and supposedly it has to be on the object is what I have read...

Comment: @RyanNaddy If you've assigned it as a texture in the *texture panel* then it should work. (It looks to me like you have, as it seems to be appearing in the render preview in the materials panel)